# How to restrict min-time ,max-time and show button image for clockpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using clock-style time picker plugin.In that i need to restrict the time, to show AM or PM and also want to add button image to that field.

Here is the code which i have added in my js file:

```
              var input = $('#field');
                input.clockpicker({
                    autoclose: true
                });

             $('#field').clockpicker({
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    align: 'left',
                    donetext: 'Done',
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are initialising your timepicker then only you have to set the mi time and max time as

```
var input = $('#single-input').clockpicker({
   twelvehour: 'true',
});
```

You can use `afterDone` or `beforeDone` method to validate the selected time. You can refrence [here](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker) and [here also](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)

Comment: The twelve hour format working fine.still i didnt get solution for min time maxtime.

Comment: That you should validate from your own like `'default': 'now'` and `afterDone: function() {$('this).val() > 'now'}`

Comment: you can also check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391567/how-to-prevent-jquery-bootstrap-clockpicker-to-get-minutes-that-are-not-divisibl